# jQuery gets wrong html() for span after a p tag

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script 
    src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript"/></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    alert($('#s1').html());
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p/>
<span id="s1"><h3>Eggs</h3>One dozen please</span>
</body>
</html>
```

This page puts up a blank alert with the <p> tag, but with <br> it shows '<h3>Eggs</h3>One dozen please', as I'd expected.

This appears to be the case with Firefox 12.0 and Chrome 19.0. IE8 gets it right. Any ideas what might be happening?

Comment: `<p>` tag requires a closing tag as well: `<p>Some text</p>`.

Comment: <p>, <p/>, or <p /> - same difference

Comment: It works if I put <br>, <br/> or <br /> in place of the <p>.

Answer (score 8):

The `/` has no meaning, at least not in HTML5. So you actually have:

```
<p>
  <span id="s1"><h3>Eggs</h3>One dozen please</span>
```

Since a `<p>` cannot contain an `<h3>`, the browser tries to make at least some sense out of it by interpreting it as:

```
<p>
  <span id="s1"></span>
</p>
<h3>Eggs</h3>One dozen please
```

Comment: For what its worth I don't think a `<span>` should contain an `h3` either since the former is inline and the latter is block and you shouldn't have block elements inside inline ones.

Comment: @Steve Teale: Because a `<br>` is self-closing (i.e. you can't have `<br>foo</br>`). As a result, it does not make the `<span>` a child, and the `<h3>` does is not placed as an illegal child. Thus, the whole issue is not applicable (you could just remove the `<br>` with the same result).

Comment: OK, thanks. I buy what you're saying, but can you point me to a page that describes the restrictions on what elements can be enclosed in what?

Comment: @Steve Teale: [The specification says](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) that `<p>` elements are only allowed to have "phrasing content" as descendants. If you click on "phrasing content" for details you'll see `<h3>` is not one of such elements.

Answer (score 2):

@pimvdb is right about closing the `<p>`

However, one other thing to note is that you have a `<h3>` which is a block element inside a `<span>` which is an inline element which is incorrect. inline elements should not contain blocks. Blocks can contain blocks and / or inlines.

For your eg. if you change the `<span>` to a `<div>` it works.

Comment: According to the specification `<span>` cannot have descendants such as `<h3>` whereas `<div>` can have them. Somehow, the `<span><h3></h3></span>` thing does get accepted by at least Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

`<p></p>`

```
$(function() {
   alert($('#s1').html());
});
```

and will work. You need to close the tag `<p></p>`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zwcPP/1/)

Comment: Please post your solution on SO, not just on jsFiddle.

Comment: @Blazemonger: Arguably, the solution *is* in the post.